# Shifter(auto) stuck in park and override won't work

Tags: automatic-transmission, shifting, fuse, tacoma

I have a 2005 Toyota Tacoma TRD that won't shift out of park.

I just came back from a 3-month trip and went to drive my truck somewhere but it wouldn't shift out of park. This has happened before as a result of a busted fuse. Usually I just press in the override and I can get it to shift while I go buy a new fuse. I tried that this time but even with the override pressed I couldn't shift out of park.

So I then checked my fuses, and found that the 10A fuse labeled "Stop" was kind of burned, although not broken. So I replaced that, but I still can't shift out of park.

How can I diagnose/fix this?

*Note: Yes I am holding the break in.*

Comment: Do you normally have to step on the brake pedal to shift it out of park? Are you currently parked on a steep incline?

Comment: @mikes Yes, I normally have to apply the brakes to shift out of park. I'm parked on flat ground in my garage.

Answer (score 2):

Do you hear a click of the brake lock disengagement from the steering column when you depress the brake pedal, with the key in, engine on? If you don't, it could be either faulty wiring to the disengagement solenoid, or the solenoid itself failed (something rather rare, but I have fixed before).

Depending on your comfort level, you could:

- Check the brake depression switch at the brake pedal for continuity. Typically pressing in the pedal a small amount will provide ground to a single wire. Ground this yourself to test the switch.
- Take the steering wheel mount's upper and lower plastic covers off
- Unplug and check for voltage between the solenoid wiring when the brake is depressed
- Manually wire a switch if the solenoid works, or
- Replace the solenoid if it does not, or
- Remove the solenoid and lock pin entirely, so you can leave park anytime you like